# How can I customise the Google Apps Script I created?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

So previously I made a script as follows:

```
  function autoReply() {
  var interval = 5;    //  if the script runs every 5 minutes; change otherwise
  var date = new Date();
  var day = date.getDay();
  var hour = date.getHours();
  if ([4,5,6,0].indexOf(day) > -1 || (day == 1 && hour < 9) || (day == 3 && hour >= 17)) {
    var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
    var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      if (threads[i].isUnread()){
      threads[i].reply("xxxx");
      threads[i].markRead();
      threads[i].markImportant();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The part

> xxxx

are the words I want my readers to check. However, they come as some plain text and I wonder how I can modify the script to include my default Gmail signature and HTML elements?

Thank you so much in advance.

Edit: I have already set my signatures for forward and reply uses. But how can I make use of them directly via the given script?
[image]

My received auto replay seems like below:
[image]

So what's wrong here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

#### Regarding the HTML body

Now you are using the `.reply(String body)` method signature. This method only accepts a String parameter representing the body of the email will be sent as reply.

In order to use more parameters such HTML body for example you will have to use the `reply(String body, Object options)` signature. This method accepts an additional JavaScript Object parameter that can contain these fields:

> - **cc**  String: a comma separated list of email addresses to CC
> - **bcc** String: a comma separated list of email addresses to BCC
> - **htmlBody**    String: if set, devices capable of rendering HTML will use it >instead of the required body argument; you can add an optional inlineImages field in HTML body if you have inlined images for your email
> - **name**    String: the name of the sender of the email (default: the user's name)
> - **from**    String: the address that the email should be sent from, which must be one of the values returned by GmailApp.getAliases()
> - **replyTo**  String: an email address to use as the default reply-to address (default: the user's email address)
> - **noReply**  Boolean:    true if the email should be sent from a generic no-reply email address to discourage recipients from responding to emails; this option is only possible for G Suite accounts, not Gmail users
> - **attachments**  BlobSource[]:   an array of files to send with the email
> - **inlineImages** Object: a JavaScript object containing a mapping from image key (String) to image data (BlobSource); this assumes that the htmlBody parameter is used and contains references to these images in the format

#### Regarding the signature

Make sure you have set your default signature for `ON REPLY/FORWARD USE` in the Gmail Settings.

### References

[GmailThread reply(String,Object)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#reply(String,Object))

[Gmail Settings](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6562?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already set my signatures in HTML format for both reply and forward in my gmail account, but the script can't make use of them? Is it possible to use my signature via this script please?

Comment: If you set your signature in the settings it will be used by the `reply()` method

Comment: Strange. My signature doesn't show up in the reply()?